# Angular 5 - ngSwitch & ngSwitchCase not to be on real element of html

Tags: angular, ng-switch

I am trying to create different html table content based on component field type properties. My concerns is  as i am manipulating html table i cannot insert any extra div inside my tbody hence using ng-template to cover this case but i am getting this exception "No provider for NgSwitch Error".

I need ngSwitch & ngSwitchCase not to be on real element of html.

this is the [stackblitz url for my scenario](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzf2vx)

Please suggest what to do here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`ngSwitch` can't be on a `<ng-template>` element, only on real elements like `<div>` or alternatively you can use `<ng-container>` instead of real elements

Here is the working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ftqywh?file=app/app.component.html

```
 <ng-container [ngSwitch]="type">
    <ng-container  *ngSwitchCase="'type1'">

<tr *ngFor="let myobj of obj">
  <td *ngFor="let data of myobj.arr"></td>
</tr>
    </ng-container>
 </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of using `ng-template` use `ng-container`